# NPM error while trying to installing @vue/cli

Tags: node.js, powershell, vue.js, npm, graphql

I've been struggling to install vuejs for an hour now, but I can't get it to work, this error keeps coming back, any ideas?

```js
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated apollo-tracing@0.15.0: The `apollo-tracing` package is no longer part of Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#tracing for details
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated graphql-extensions@0.15.0: The `graphql-extensions` API has been removed from Apollo Server 3. Use the plugin API instead: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/
npm WARN deprecated apollo-cache-control@0.14.0: The functionality provided by the `apollo-cache-control` package is built in to `apollo-server-core` starting with Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#cachecontrol for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.19: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@4.0.8: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\amber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@apollo\protobufjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ^"C:\Windows\TEMP^ \postinstall-1656074175378.cmd^"
npm ERR! '"C:\Windows\TEMP \postinstall-1656074175378.cmd"' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
npm ERR! ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\amber\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-24T12_35_51_489Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried to delete all the contents of the NPM folder, delete view and reinstall, clear the cache but nothing to do.

I really need your help :/

Comment: Two other things you could try are `npm clear cache` and manually deleting that `C:\Windows\TEMP \postinstall-1656074175378.cmd` file. Looks like it's having a hard time recognizing that path so clearing/resetting it might help.

Comment: I tried everything you told me but still nothing